# Reattempting of failed bulk inserts in pymongo

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to do a bulk insert of documents into a MongoDB collection in Python, using *pymongo*. This is what the code looks like:

`collection_name.insert_many([ logs[i] for i in range (len(logs)) ])`

where *logs* is a list of dictionaries of variable length.

This works fine when there are no issues with any of the logs. However, if any one of the logs has some kind of issue and pymongo refuses to save it (say, the issue is something like the document fails to match the validation schema set for that collection), the entire bulk insert is rolled back and no documents are inserted in the database.

Is there any way I can retry the bulk insert by ignoring only the defective log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore those types of errors by specifying `ordered: false` as an option: `collection.insert_many(logs, ordered=False)`. All operations are attempted before raising an exception, which you can catch.

See https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many